# How to resolve "No credentials available" Issue in google One Tap Login?

Tags: yolo, credential-providers

I am working in one project in which I need to integrate `Google One Tap Login` which show All accounts list that were currently logged in into browser.

`One Tap Login` Iframe is adding successfully in localhost environment but With the use of same `PROVIDER_ID`, When I deploy my project into server with staging url.

I got Issue with Open Iframe. It is always show error like "noCredentialsAvailable: No credential is available for the current user." But I already have login with two accounts in gmail.

I can't understand this kind of behaviour of `Iframe`.

Another question of StackOverflow say's that put button of `Google` for login  via google. but I want to resolve this issue.

Is there any missing code from my side ?

Same `Prvider ID` is used in **Localhost** and **Staging(subdomain)** Still Error is occur.